# Highlight feature with effects and blending in Arcgis JavaScript Api

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server

I am using this sample, which uses layer blending and effect on multiple layers to create a more artistic way of highlighting features selected by the user. When the application loads, the basemap is displayed over all other layers in the map. When a user clicks on a country, the country will be highlighted.

The light gray canvas vector tiles layer and a countries feature layer are added to a group layer and the destination-over blendMode is set on the group layer. With the destination-over blendMode, the background layer covers, or is placed over, the top layer. The content of the top layer is visible where both layers do not overlap. When the app loads, you see the modern antique vector tiles basemap on top of the groupLayer.

My question is, is there a way to do the same with Feature Access instead of using portal ID.

```
   <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"
    />
    <title>
      Highlight feature with effects and blending | Sample | ArcGIS API for
      JavaScript 4.21
    </title>
    <style>
      html,
      body,
      #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
      #messageDiv {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
      }
    </style>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.21/esri/themes/light/main.css"
    />
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.21/"></script>

    <script>
      require([
        "esri/WebMap",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/layers/VectorTileLayer",
        "esri/Graphic",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
        "esri/layers/GroupLayer"
      ], (
        WebMap,
        MapView,
        VectorTileLayer,
        Graphic,
        FeatureLayer,
        GraphicsLayer,
        GroupLayer
      ) => {
        const map = new WebMap({
          basemap: {
            portalItem: {
              id: "f35ef07c9ed24020aadd65c8a65d3754" // modern antique vector tiles
            }
          }
        });
        const vtLayer = new VectorTileLayer({
          portalItem: {
            id: "2afe5b807fa74006be6363fd243ffb30" // gray vector tiles canvas
          }
        });
        const countries = new FeatureLayer({
          portalItem: {
            id: "53a1e68de7e4499cad77c80daba46a94" // boundaries of countries
          }
        });
        // This group layer groups the gray canvas vector tiles and
        // countries feature layer.
        // With destination-over blendMode, the background layer covers
        // the top layer. The top layer is put behind the destination layer.
        // So when the app starts, the basemap layer will be shown over this layer
        const groupLayer = new GroupLayer({
          layers: [vtLayer, countries],
          blendMode: "destination-over"
        });
        map.add(groupLayer);
        const view = new MapView({
          container: "viewDiv",
          map: map,
          zoom: 6,
          center: [2, 46],
          constraints: {
            snapToZoom: false,
            minScale: 147914381
          }
        });
        let layerView, animation;
        // countryGraphicsLayer is added to the view's basemap.
        // It will contain black polygon covering the extent of the world
        // the country graphic will also be added to this layer when user clicks a country.
        // With destination-in blend mode, the contents of background layer is
        // kept where it overlaps with top layer. Everything else is made transparent.
        // In this case, the countryGraphicsLayer will be displayed underneath
        // modern antique vector tiles basemap.
        // The bloom effect will add a glow around the selected country.
        const countryGraphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer({
          blendMode: "destination-in",
          effect: "bloom(200%)"
        });
        map.loadAll().then(async () => {
          addWorld();
          map.basemap.baseLayers.getItemAt(1).blendMode = "multiply";
          // add the buffer graphicslayer to the basemap
          map.basemap.baseLayers.add(countryGraphicsLayer);
          // get a reference ot the countries featurelayer's layerview
          // layerview will be queried to get the intersecting country
          // when user clicks on the map
          layerView = await view.whenLayerView(countries);
        });
        view.ui.add("messageDiv", "top-right");
        const symbol = {
          type: "simple-fill",
          color: "white",
          outline: null
        };
        // listen to the view's click event
        view.on("click", async (event) => {
          // query the countries featurelayer for a country that intersects the point
          // user clicked on
          const {
            features: [feature]
          } = await layerView.queryFeatures({
            geometry: view.toMap(event),
            returnGeometry: true,
            maxAllowableOffset: 10000,
            outFields: ["*"]
          });
          countryGraphicsLayer.graphics.removeAll();
          animation && animation.remove();
          let world = addWorld();
          // add the clicked country feature to the graphicslayer
          if (feature) {
            feature.symbol = symbol;
            countryGraphicsLayer.graphics.add(feature);
            // add a fade animation to show the highlight effect
            // for the selected country
            animation = fadeWorld(world);
            // zoom to the highlighted country
            view.goTo(
              {
                target: view.toMap(event),
                extent: feature.geometry.extent.clone().expand(1.8)
              },
              { duration: 1000 }
            );
          }
        });
        function addWorld(world) {
          world = new Graphic({
            geometry: {
              type: "extent",
              xmin: -180,
              xmax: 180,
              ymin: -90,
              ymax: 90
            },
            symbol: {
              type: "simple-fill",
              color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
              outline: null
            }
          });
          countryGraphicsLayer.graphics.add(world);
          return world;
        }
        // add a fading animation when user clicks on a country
        function fadeWorld(world) {
          let timer;
          // requestAnimationFrame method specifies "frame" function
          // to perform an animation where the opacity of the world polygon graphic
          // decreased by 0.1 until it is 0 or completely transparent
          // then the animation is cancelled
          function frame() {
            const symbol = world.symbol.clone();
            symbol.color.a = Math.max(0, symbol.color.a - 0.1);
            world.symbol = symbol;
            if (symbol.color.a > 0) {
              timer = requestAnimationFrame(frame);
            }
          }
          frame();
          return {
            remove() {
              cancelAnimationFrame(timer);
            }
          };
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
    <div id="messageDiv" class="esri-widget esri-heading">
      <h4 class="esri-heading">Click on a country</h4>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean with *Feature Access*?, you want to create the layers with url instead of *portal ID*?.